# How to Update ComboBox ItemsSource Without Flickering

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am struggling with an update to a `ComboBox` that previously worked.  I originally had its `ItemsSource` bound to a read-only `ObservableCollection<char>` property in the ViewModel.  When the user instigates changes (which is done with mouse strokes, so dozens of times per second in some cases), the get rebuilds the collection from the Model and returns it.

When I changed to my own object in the `ObservableCollection`, the `ComboBox` started flickering during updates.  I'm not sure what's going wrong.  Here's the code that works, starting with the XAML:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource='{Binding FromBins}' SelectedValue='{Binding SelectedFromBin, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}' />
```

ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<char> FromBins
    {
        get
        {
            ObservableCollection<char> tempBins = new ObservableCollection<char>();
            foreach (var item in Map.BinCounts)
            {
                tempBins.Add(item.Key);
            }
            return tempBins;
        }
    }
```

I simply raise a property change with every mouse movement and the interface works as expected (there is some other logic to ensure the `SelectedItem` is valid).

To make the interface more useful, I decided to add more information to the `ComboBox`, using my own class:

```
public class BinItem : IEquatable<BinItem>
{
    public char Bin { get; set; }
    public SolidColorBrush BinColor { get; set; }
    public string BinColorToolTip { get {...} }

    public BinItem( char bin )
    {
        Bin = bin;
        BinColor = new SolidColorBrush(BinColors.GetBinColor(bin));
    }

    public bool Equals(BinItem other)
    {
        return other.Bin == Bin ? true : false;
    }
}
```

If I swap `char` out for `BinItem` in the working code ViewModel I get flickering as the mouse is moved.  Here is the updated XAML:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource='{Binding FromBins}' SelectedValue='{Binding SelectedFromBin, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}'>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ToolTip='{Binding BinColorToolTip}'>
                <Rectangle Fill='{Binding BinColor}' Width='10' Height='10' HorizontalAlignment='Center' VerticalAlignment='Center' Margin='0,0,4,0' Stroke='#FF747474' />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Bin}" Width='16' />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

I have tried numerous things, including but not limited to:
-Using a `List` instead of the `ObservableCollection` but even though the `Get` fires every time and returns the correct collection of items, the interface does not always update (though the flickering disappears).
-Leaving all possible bins in the items source and adding a `Visibility` property to the BinItem class that I bound to (couldn't get it to update).

I suspect I am doing something fundamentally wrong, but no amount of searching SO or otherwise has helped thus far.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: As a note, using an ObservableCollection only makes sense when you add or remove items to/from the same collection object (that is kept as ItemsSource). When you always replace the collection instance, you don't need it.

Comment: It's probably flickering from the constant refreshing of the list every time the list is called. When you're populating this list, how much is it changing? Are you just appending to the list or is it drastically changing each time? Because it may be worthwhile to just pre-populate the ObservableCollection

Comment: Cache changes, only update every x seconds.

Comment: Clemens, any idea why the UI sometimes failed to refresh when I used a `List<T>` instead?

Chris, the collection will fluctuate quite a bit during editing but no more than one addition and one subtraction per refresh, which is why I was rebuilding it every time.  I suspect the brute-force method from my answer isn't the best way but I'm guessing it works because at no point is the collection ever empty or null.

Will, thanks for the suggestion, I'd have tried that next if the manual additions/subtractions didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this using the ideas from Clemens and Chris.  Not sure if this is the most elegant solution, but it works as intended with no measurable performance hit.

Instead of replacing the collection with each refresh, I go through the logic of finding out what's changed (with each update there could be an addition AND a removal simultaneously).  Code below:

```
private ObservableCollection<BinItem> _FromBins = new ObservableCollection<BinItem>();

public ObservableCollection<BinItem> FromBins
{
    get
    {
        if (_FromBins.Count > 0)
        {
            List<char> BinsToRemove = new List<char>();
            foreach (var item in _FromBins)
            {
                if (!Map.BinCounts.ContainsKey(item.Bin))
                {
                    BinsToRemove.Add(item.Bin);
                }
            } 
            foreach (var item in BinsToRemove)
            {
                _FromBins.Remove(new BinItem(item));
            }
        }
        foreach (var item in Map.BinCounts)
        {
            if (!_FromBins.Contains(new BinItem(item.Key)) && item.Value > 0)                   {
                _FromBins.Add(new BinItem(item.Key));
            }
        }
        return _FromBins;
    }
}
```

Hope this can help someone else too.